# Is there a rule for anti noise earpieces?

Tags: rules

Few days ago, one of my opponent wore Bose anti noise earpieces. Of course, I didn't call the referee cause I knew that it wasn't a cheat technique. But I was wondering what is the rules for that kind of object. I think that some players could confuse with earphones and call referee for cheat attempt.
Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the implied difference between "earpiece" and "earphone", particularly since neither of those terms seem to be use by Bose?

Comment: Yes, from my point of view, an earphones is for listen music, an earpiece is like the Bose SleepBuds, just to attenuate the noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I was wondering what is the rules for that kind of object.

Strictly speaking they are not allowed without the arbiter's permission.

This is what the latest [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=208&view=article) state:

> 11.3.2.1 During a game, a player is forbidden to have any electronic device not specifically approved by the arbiter in the playing venue.
>
> However, the regulations of an event may allow such devices to be
>   stored in a player’s bag, provided the device is completely switched
>   off. This bag must be placed as agreed with the arbiter. Both players
>   are forbidden to use this bag without permission of the arbiter.
>
> 11.3.2.2 If it is evident that a player has such a device on their person in the playing venue, the player shall lose the game. The
>   opponent shall win. The regulations of an event may specify a
>   different, less severe, penalty.